# Convergence of $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^{µ(k)}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

For which $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is the sum

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^{µ(k)}}$$
$$µ\left(k\right) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       \alpha & : k\ is\ even\\
       \beta & : k\ is\ odd
     \end{array}
   \right.\\$$

convergent?

Am I allowed to split it into

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2k)^{\alpha}}$$
and
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2k-1)^{\beta}}$$
and to conclude that it converges only if both of those sums converge?

Comment: What about $\alpha$ and $\beta$

Comment: $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are real numbers

Comment: What about they value? Do they more than 1?

Comment: the values are completely arbitrary

Comment: I guess it depend of value of this constants

Answer (score 1):

More generally, you can prove that:

> If $a_k$ is an infinite sequence of non-negative numbers then
>   $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k$ converges if any only if both $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_{2k}$ and $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_{2k-1}$ converge.